# How can I use puppeth via geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, homebrew

I want to create a private ethereum network on mac and I've already installed geth via homebrew but the command `puppeth` is not working.
`zsh: command not found: puppeth`
I've read on other forums that puppeth was removed from geth.
How can I configure the network?

Comment: Yes, puppeth has been dropped from geth repository. There's a guide how to configure your own private network in the official site https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network.